# pre-allocate CPU for the screen magnifier

Tags: macos, performance, accessibility

Lately, my mac seems to be having CPU spikes at certain times. I'm not sure there's a single culprit. Sometimes, Docker has a ridiculously high CPU usage, sometimes it's Chrome. The annoying thing is that it also makes the mac's built-in screen magnifier insanely laggy, which is frustrating. Is there a way that I can make the OS guarantee that whatever process is responsible for the magnifier gets enough CPU cycles to run smoothly?

[image]